# 14.04 or HWE 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I know this question is similar to others but I was unable to find a duplicate that answered my specific question.

Background:

I have purchased a new computer.
I will be booting only Ubuntu. No OS will be installed when it arrives. 
I prefer to stay with 14.04 if possible so that I can wait until the first update of 16.04.
I currently have the original version of 14.04. I *may* need to use xorg-edgers ppa for the best graphic card support(card I bought(Geforce GTX 970) is supported in 346.xx + but some of the games I play may do better with newer drivers)

Question:

Should I install my old copy of 14.04 or should I download the newer update that will use the newer(HWE) kernels for best performace/least issues?

I ask because I'm not sure if xorg-edgers ppa will work with the HWE kernels.

Another side of the same question; would it be better to just download 15.04 and install it with the same goal in mind?

---

Note to any potential close voters: While this may seem like a opinion or poll based question, it is not, I am asking for educated advise not an opinion.

Note to any answerers: Please give me only educated advise with some reasoning as to why you say that so that my question does not get closed as opinion based(and it will also give me the information I need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a new PC then just get the point release 14.04 with HWE; the entire reason they exist is for new hardware support, so if you're buying a new PC then you might as well get the new Xorg/kernel for your latest hardware.

For your GTX 970 use this PPA so you can get the newest nvidia drivers without needing to mess with the rest of your Xorg stack: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: ahh, Thank you, Thank you , Thank you.  even better than I expected, I wasn't aware of this ppa.  I can run the latest drivers with a much better chance of no breaking my Xorg!!! [happy dance]

Comment: There is no need to use any ppa. Driver `nvidia-346` supports this adapter from official repositories.